# Save Tensorflow graph for viewing in Tensorboard without summary operations

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I have a rather complicated Tensorflow graph that I'd like to visualize for optimization purposes. Is there a function that I can call that will simply save the graph for viewing in Tensorboard without needing to annotate variables?

I Tried this:

```
merged = tf.merge_all_summaries()
writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("/Users/Name/Desktop/tf_logs", session.graph_def)
```

But no output was produced. This is using the 0.6 wheel.

This appears to be related:
[Graph visualisaton is not showing in tensorboard for seq2seq model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33773271/graph-visualisaton-is-not-showing-in-tensorboard-for-seq2seq-model)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For efficiency, the [`tf.train.SummaryWriter`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/train.html#SummaryWriter) logs asynchronously to disk. To ensure that the graph appears in the log, you must call [`close()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/train.html#SummaryWriter.close) or [`flush()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/train/adding_summaries_to_event_files#SummaryWriter.flush) on the writer before the program exits.

Comment: `tf.summary.FileWriter` for recent versions of TF

Answer (score 17):

You can also dump the graph as a GraphDef protobuf and load that directly in TensorBoard.  You can do this without starting a session or running the model.

```
## ... create graph ...
>>> graph_def = tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()
>>> graphpb_txt = str(graph_def)
>>> with open('graphpb.txt', 'w') as f: f.write(graphpb_txt)
```

This will output a file that looks something like this, depending on the specifics of your model.

```
node {
  name: "W"
  op: "Const"
  attr {
    key: "dtype"
    value {
      type: DT_FLOAT
    }
  }
...
version 1
```

In TensorBoard you can then use the "Upload" button to load it from disk.

Comment: where is this "Upload" button? I didn't see any

Comment: There is no `Upload` button

Comment: I'm a Newbie here.
So, how to upload? Thx!

Comment: Upload is in the "Graph" section of the UI, in the panel on the left.

Comment: I had to remove "a." before "graph.as_graph_def())" to not get a NameError. Output looks ok.

Comment: There is no panel on the left of the "Graphs" tab if I run tensorboard --logdir ./ with no summary output.

Comment: I think you mean:    >>> graph_def = tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()
>>> graphpb_txt = str(graph_def)
>>> with open('graphpb.txt', 'w') as f: f.write(graphpb_txt)         This comment is for new users of tensorflow.

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me:

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    ... build graph (without annotations) ...
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir='logdir', graph=graph)
writer.flush()
```

The graph is loaded automatically when launching tensorboard with "--logdir=logdir/". No "upload" button needed.

Comment: Thanks to y g (user 5656195) for fixing the typo "FileWrite" instead of "FileWriter".

3 reviewers rejected this edit saying "intended to address the author" (presumably because y g put a question mark at the end of the edit explanation). Crazy.

Comment: tf.train.SummaryWriter is deprecated, instead use tf.summary.FileWriter.

Answer (score 4):

For all clarity, this is how I used the `.flush()` method and resolved the issue:

Initialize the writer with:

```
writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("/home/rob/Dropbox/ConvNets/tf/log_tb", sess.graph_def)
```

and use the writer with:

```
writer.add_summary(summary_str, i)
    writer.flush()
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing worked for me except this

```
# Helper for Converting Frozen graph from Disk to TF serving compatible Model
def get_graph_def_from_file(graph_filepath):
  tf.reset_default_graph()
  with ops.Graph().as_default():
    with tf.gfile.GFile(graph_filepath, 'rb') as f:
      graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
      graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
      return graph_def

#let us get the output nodes from the graph
graph_def =get_graph_def_from_file('/coding/ssd_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28/frozen_inference_graph.pb')

with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as session:
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir='/coding/log_tb/1', graph=session.graph)
    writer.flush()
```

Then using TB worked

```
#ssh -L 6006:127.0.0.1:6006 root@<remoteip> # for tensor board - in your local machine type 127.0.0.1
!tensorboard --logdir '/coding/log_tb/1'
```

Comment: I'm just curious why do we need the `session`? Can we do it by calling `tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()` instead?